# Antlr4 left recursive rule contains a left recursive alternative which can be followed by the empty string

Tags: antlr4, left-recursion

So I defined a grammar to parse an C style syntax language:

```
grammar mygrammar;

program
: (declaration)*
  (statement)*
  EOF
;

declaration
: INT ID '=' expression ';'
;

assignment
: ID '=' expression ';'
;

expression
: expression (op=('*'|'/') expression)*
| expression (op=('+'|'-') expression)*
| relation
| INT
| ID
| '(' expression ')'
;

relation
: expression (op=('<'|'>') expression)*
;

statement
: expression ';'
| ifstatement
| loopstatement
| printstatement
| assignment
;

ifstatement
: IF '(' expression ')' (statement)* FI ';'
;

loopstatement
: LOOP '(' expression ')' (statement)* POOL ';'
;

printstatement
: PRINT '(' expression ')' ';'
;

IF : 'if';
FI : 'fi';
LOOP : 'loop';
POOL : 'pool';
INT : 'int';
PRINT : 'print';
ID : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

And I can parse a simple test as this:

```
int i = (2+3)*3/2*(3+36);
int j = i;
int k = 2*1+i*3;
if (k > 2)
  k = k + 1;
  i = i / 3;
  j = j / 3;
fi;
loop (i < 10)
  i = i + 1 * (i+k);
  j = (j + 1) * (j-k);
  k = i + j;
  print(k);
pool;
```

However, when I want to generate ANTLR Recogonizers in intelliJ, I got this error:

> sCalc.g4:19:0: left recursive rule expression contains a left recursive alternative which can be followed by the empty string

I wonder if this is caused by my `ID` could be an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your grammar:

- you have `INT` as an alternative inside `expression` while you probably want `INTEGER` instead
- there is no need to do `expression (op=('+'|'-') expression)*`: this will do: `expression op=('+'|'-') expression`
- ANTLR4 does not support indirect left recursive rules: you must include `relation` inside `expression`

Something like this ought to do it:

```
grammar mygrammar;

program
: (declaration)*
  (statement)*
  EOF
;

declaration
: INT ID '=' expression ';'
;

assignment
: ID '=' expression ';'
;

expression
: expression op=('*'|'/') expression
| expression op=('+'|'-') expression
| expression op=('<'|'>') expression
| INTEGER
| ID
| '(' expression ')'
;

statement
: expression ';'
| ifstatement
| loopstatement
| printstatement
| assignment
;

ifstatement
: IF '(' expression ')' (statement)* FI ';'
;

loopstatement
: LOOP '(' expression ')' (statement)* POOL ';'
;

printstatement
: PRINT '(' expression ')' ';'
;

IF : 'if';
FI : 'fi';
LOOP : 'loop';
POOL : 'pool';
INT : 'int';
PRINT : 'print';
ID : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
INTEGER : [0-9]+;
WS : [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

Also not that this `(statement)*` can simply be written as `statement*`

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I also want to know how can antlr4 simply match 0 to many statement without catch a group of them using `'()'`

Comment: Err, I don't understand. `(a)*` is simply the same as `a*`. If you have more than 1 thing to repeat, then you nee to put parenthesis around them: `(a b)*` (not the same as `a b*`)

Answer (score 2):

It's about your `expression` and `relation` rules. The expression rule can match `relation` in one alt, which in turn recurses back to `expression.` Rule `relation` additionally can potentially match nothing because of `(op=('<'|'>') expression)*`

A better approach is probably to have `relation` call `expression` and remove the `relation` alt from `expression`. Then use `relation` everywhere you used `expression` now. That's a typical scenario in expressions, starting out with low precedence operations as top level rules and drilling down to higher precedence rules, ultimately ending at a simple expression rule (or similar).